# Can't connect to remote server. Socket error = #2000

Tags: linux, firewall, port, timeout, ftp

I don't know what went wrong, but I get a Timeout after logging in to the proftpd server.

```
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Getting listing ""...
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Resolving host name mydomain.com...
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Host name mydomain.com resolved: ip = 176.28.54.199.
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Connecting to FTP server... mydomain.com:21 (ip = 176.28.54.244)...
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Socket connected. Waiting for welcome message...
        [12.05.2014 16:30:24] 220 ProFTPD 1.3.4c Server (ProFTPD) [176.28.54.199]
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Connected. Authenticating...
COMMAND:>   [12.05.2014 16:30:24] USER nx6_ftp_usr
        [12.05.2014 16:30:24] 331 Password required for nx6_ftp_usr
COMMAND:>   [12.05.2014 16:30:24] PASS *****
        [12.05.2014 16:30:24] 230 User nx6_ftp_usr logged in
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Login successful.
COMMAND:>   [12.05.2014 16:30:24] PWD
        [12.05.2014 16:30:24] 257 "/" is the current directory
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Home directory: /
COMMAND:>   [12.05.2014 16:30:24] FEAT
        [12.05.2014 16:30:24] Informational Message Only:
        211-Features:
         MDTM
         MFMT
         TVFS
         UTF8
         AUTH TLS
         MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
         MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;
         LANG en-US*
         PBSZ
         PROT
         REST STREAM
         SIZE
        211 End
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] This site supports features.
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] This site supports SIZE.
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:24] This site can resume broken downloads.
COMMAND:>   [12.05.2014 16:30:24] REST 0
        [12.05.2014 16:30:24] 350 Restarting at 0. Send STORE or RETRIEVE to initiate transfer
COMMAND:>   [12.05.2014 16:30:24] PASV
        [12.05.2014 16:30:25] 227 Entering Passive Mode (176,28,54,199,160,55).
COMMAND:>   [12.05.2014 16:30:25] LIST
STATUS:>    [12.05.2014 16:30:25] Connecting FTP data socket... 176.28.54.199:41015...
ERROR:>     [12.05.2014 16:30:35] Can't connect to remote server. Socket error = #2000.
ERROR:>     [12.05.2014 16:30:35] Timeout (10000 ms).
```

I double checked that port 21 isn't blocked, my internet connection is fine as well and the login works in general. What is looking strange to me is the part after the IP (160,55) after entering passive mode, and the try to connect to port 41015 after the LIST command.

Somebody here with an idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ftp uses 2 ports, 20/TCP DATA Port,
21/TCP Control Port

check your firewall,routing settings for that port aswell.
Depending on your connection to the server you might need to port-forward the passive port rage to the client pc aswell.

Comment: @DennisNolte You're right, setting PORT instead of PASV connection worked. If you put an answer how to port-forward the passive port (what port this will be?), I can mark your answer as correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ftp uses 2 ports, 20/TCP DATA Port, 21/TCP Control Port check your firewall,routing settings for that port aswell. Depending on your connection to the server you might need to port-forward the passive port rage.

see [Proftpd online documents](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_PassivePorts.html)

set in the config file:

```
#example range
PassivePorts 49152 65534
```

Depending on how many connections you need to the server a few ports should be enough.

```
PassivePorts 50000 50010
```

Dont forgot to reload or restart the proftpd deamon.

Then you would connect to your (home) router and set "port forwarding" "game application sharing" or similiar named (depending on the brand of your router)

How you exactly port forward the ports to your PC is written in the manual of your router usually.